# Some maximization over stochastic matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization

I am writing some applied assignment which leads me to the following problem. I will be very grateful if anyone can provide a solution or even some thoughts. Thanks a lot!

Consider a (row-)stochastic $N\times N$ matrix $W$ with all diagonal being $0$ and a scalar $\beta\in(0,1)$.

Denote $V$ as the limit of the following series
\begin{equation}
V=\lim_{t\to\infty}I+\beta W+\cdots+(\beta W)^t=(I-\beta W)^{-1}
\end{equation}
Note there is NO additional structure on $W$ (so it can be (ir)regular, (a)periodic etc.). But I think the sum still converges as $\beta^t\stackrel{t\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$ thus $(\beta W)^t\stackrel{t\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\mathbf{0}$. Am I correct? If no, why not?

My question is the following: how to construct $W$ given the constraints (i.e. it is stochastic and all diagonals are $0$) such that the following is maximized

\begin{equation}
\max_{\{w_{ij}\}_{i,j\in\{1,\dots,N\}}} i^TWV^Ti\hspace{4ex}s.t. \sum_{j=1}^Nw_{ij}=1,\ w_{ii}=0,\ w_{ij}\geq0,\ \ i,j=1,\dots,N
\end{equation}

where $i$ is a $N$-vector of 1. The objective function above can also be rewritten as
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^N\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N v_{ij}w_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^NV_kW_k
\end{equation}
where $V_k$ denotes the sum of $k^{th}$ column of $V$ and $W_k$ that of $W$.

I've tried some numerical examples and it seems that the maximum is obtained when $W$ has the following form
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0&\cdots&0\\
1&0&0&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots\\
1&0&0&\cdots&0
\end{bmatrix}

But I fail to prove it; perhaps I overlook something very obvious...

Comment: Assuming that your definition of "row-stochastic matrix" is the standard, ie non-negative entries, then not only $(\beta W)^t\rightarrow \boldsymbol{0}$ (which is not sufficient for convergence of the sum), but each element of $(\beta W)^t$ is no bigger than $\beta^t$, and that is sufficient for convergence, so yes, $V$ is well-defined.

Comment: Yes my definition is standard. Thanks for the clarification!